# Get an object list from an HQL query with joint

Tags: jpa, ejb, hql, jointjs

I have two tables: Customers and Commands, it's a `@OneToMany` relation from Client to Commands, one client have many Commands.
the table commands contain : `idCommand, date, nameCommande, idCustomer`.
the table customers contain: `idCustomer, nameClient, email`.
All the JPA and EJB are set up and I can easily get a list of Commands or Clients using an HQL query in a managed bean and list them in a JSP using this code.

```
 public List<Commande> selectAllCommandes() {
    List<Commande> commandes = em.createQuery("select c from Commande c").getResultList();
      return commandes;
}
 public List<Customer> selectAllCustomers() {
    List<Customer> customers = em.createQuery("select cu from Customer cu").getResultList();
    return customers;
}
```

How do I join the two tables with the `idCustomer` column in a way to show the name of client instead his id? I've used this HQL query

`SELECT c.date, c.name Commande, cu.nameClient FROM Commande AS c, Customer AS cu  WHERE cu.idCustomer = c.idCustomer`

But I have no idea about the `List<>` type that I need to use to get the result/

Comment: @AndroidLearner: API/library/framework/software names like "JSF", "EJB", "JPA", "JSP", etc are **not** code! Please stop formatting them as code. Only format phrases which you also really use in code as code.

Comment: @BalusC: I'll keep in my mind.Thanks for your valuable suggestion... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you map the reverse relation in the `Commande` entity ...

```
public class Commande {
    ...

    @ManyToOne(mappedBy="commande")
    private Client client;

    // getter and setter ...
}
```

<sub>(Here, `mappedBy` is getting the name of the `@OneToMany` property set up at the
other side of the relationship)</sub>

Then after executing your query `SELECT c FROM Commande c` you would get a list of `Commande` objects, and for each one of them you could get the name of the client using: `thisCommande.getClient().getName()`.